# MediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.NaturalDuration always returns zero

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaplayerelement

I'm working on a TTS (Text to Speech) application and I need to present the duration of each speech. The problem is that it always returns zero. Any help is most welcome. Thanks.

```
    SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    MediaPlayerElement mediaPlayerElement = new MediaPlayerElement();
    SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Some text...");
    mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream, stream.ContentType);
    mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
    string strDuration = mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.NaturalDuration.Milliseconds.ToString();
    MessageDialog msgDlg = new MessageDialog(strDuration);
    await msgDlg.ShowAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.NaturalDuration always returns zero

I saw that, it looks that we can't  `MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.NaturalDuration.Milliseconds` get method. I will report that, currently we have a workaround that get the [`NaturalDuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybacksession.naturalduration?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Media_Playback_MediaPlaybackSession_NaturalDuration) in  [`NaturalDurationChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybacksession.naturaldurationchanged?view=winrt-20348) event.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    MediaPlayerElement mediaPlayerElement = new MediaPlayerElement();
    SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("say hello ");
    mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream, stream.ContentType);
    mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
    mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.NaturalDurationChanged += PlaybackSession_NaturalDurationChanged; ;

}

private async void PlaybackSession_NaturalDurationChanged(Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlaybackSession sender, object args)
{
    var duration = sender.NaturalDuration;
    MessageDialog msgDlg = new MessageDialog(duration.TotalSeconds.ToString()+"s");
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
     {
         await msgDlg.ShowAsync();

     });

}
```